# Interchangeability of where and when?

Tags: meaning, grammar

> This is the day where I will arise to redeem your life and fully
> restore it back to Me.
>
> [I Hear His Whisper Volume 2: 52 Devotions
> Brian Simmons · 2016](https://www.google.com/books/edition/I_Hear_His_Whisper_Volume_2/ujJEDQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22+the+day+where+i+will%22&pg=PT117&printsec=frontcover)

[M-W Learner's Dictionary: Where](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/where)

The dictionary says that both are interchangeable, but to what extent and is this true at all? I often hear "the day where" used to mean "the day when", is this grammatical or not?

Comment: The explanation of 'what is happening' is that time is being metaphorically represented by space. This seems a logical pairing with say 'Do you remember the episode where/when ...?' but can lead to less natural sounding examples where times are mentioned more directly ' ... that was the day where ...'. Metaphors can't be judged ungrammatical, but they can certainly be judged unidiomatic.

Comment: So where and when are interchangeable?

Comment: I can't see any reason to use a locative adjunct when referring to a temporal situation.

Comment: @Benjamin Harman You're welcome! Yes, I cringe at *mine*. I did get what you were saying btw :) I'll delete my comment, and this one in a little while. Do yours and we can pretend we never make mistakes!